# Screen goes blank and app force closes itself

Tags: java, android

The following method I have used to open a notepad file which i have saved in my raw folder.

Whenever I open this method, A new blank screen is opened (fully black) and app force closes itself.

```
public class Fest1 extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fest1);
    text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textV);
    text.setText(readTxt());
}
private String readTxt(){

    InputStream inputStream=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    int i;
    try{
       i=inputStream.read();
        while (i!=1)
        {
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(i);
            i = inputStream.read();
        }
        inputStream.close();
        }catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return byteArrayOutputStream.toString();
    }

    }
```

The log:

> 02-06 10:02:11.345 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Starting a blocking GC Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.345
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.349 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Starting a blocking GC Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.357
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Alloc partial concurrent
>   mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace objects, 1(64MB) LOS objects,
>   2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 632us total 7.967ms 02-06 10:02:11.357
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.364 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 601us total 6.660ms 02-06
>   10:02:11.364 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Forcing
>   collection of SoftReferences for 256MB allocation 02-06 10:02:11.364
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.371 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 599us total 6.876ms 02-06
>   10:02:11.371 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival W/art: Throwing
>   OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with
>   4194304 free bytes and 251MB until OOM" 02-06 10:02:11.371
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.371 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Starting a blocking GC Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.376
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.381 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6(144B) AllocSpace
>   objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 585us total
>   5.443ms 02-06 10:02:11.382 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.388
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Alloc concurrent mark
>   sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 2% free,
>   132MB/136MB, paused 599us total 6.748ms 02-06 10:02:11.389
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Forcing collection of
>   SoftReferences for 256MB allocation 02-06 10:02:11.389
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a blocking GC
>   Alloc 02-06 10:02:11.396 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art:
>   Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3(72B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B)
>   LOS objects, 2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 612us total 7.157ms 02-06
>   10:02:11.396 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: Starting a
>   blocking GC HomogeneousSpaceCompact 02-06 10:02:11.402
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival I/art: HomogeneousSpaceCompact
>   marksweep + semispace GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS
>   objects, 2% free, 132MB/136MB, paused 5.670ms total 5.670ms 02-06
>   10:02:11.402 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival W/art: Throwing
>   OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with
>   4194304 free bytes and 251MB until OOM" 02-06 10:02:11.402
>   4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down
>   VM 02-06 10:02:11.402 4026-4026/com.example.krishna.festival
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: com.example.krishna.festival, PID: 4026
>                                                                               java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte
>   allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 251MB until OOM
>                                                                                   at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3256)
>                                                                                   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
>                                                                                   at
>   java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
>                                                                                   at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122)
>                                                                                   at com.example.krishna.festival.Fest1.readTxt(Fest1.java:32)
>                                                                                   at com.example.krishna.festival.Fest1.onCreate(Fest1.java:21)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

Comment: Please share the relevant log so we can see the exception and the stack trace

Comment: please add your logcat

Comment: `while (i!=1)` - surely `while (i!=-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inputStream.read()` returns -1 at the end of stream. Your `while (i!=1)` checks for 1 instead of -1 and gets into an infinite loop. This grows `byteArrayOutputStream` to a huge size, eventually exceeding memory and causing the crash. Fix your `while` statement.

Comment: Thanks . It worked !

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at the log. The relevant lines are:

```
com.example.krishna.festival, PID: 4026 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 268435468 byte allocation with 4194304 free bytes and 251MB until OOM at
```

and

```
java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:122) at
```

So, basically, your write to the Byte Array Output Stream is causing an Out Of Memory Exception.

As @degs indicated, this is because you have an infinite loop that will cause your program to keep writing to the Stream until you run out of memory.